# What is the relationship between orbital altitude and orbital speed?

Tags: orbital-motion

I know that if an object has a higher orbit, it will orbit at a lower speed. However, I don't know what the exact relationship is. Is the decrease in speed linear, or quadratic, or something else?

Also, as a bonus question: higher orbits not only have the objects moving slower, but they also have a larger distance to cover. What is the relationship between orbital altitude and the time to complete a full orbit? Is it linear, quadratic, cubic...?

(For the purposes of this question, assume altitude means from the center of the Earth).

Comment: The answer should be in any textbook on mechanics.

Comment: [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/482824/how-does-the-orbital-radius-affects-the-orbital-velocity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To orbit in a circle you need a certain amount of acceleration
$$a_c=\frac{v^2}r$$
where $a_c$ stands for centripetal acceleration. Or in other words to orbit with velocity $v$ at a radius $r$ you need this specific acceleration $a_c$.

The gravitational pull between two bodies is given by
$$F=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$$
With $M$ the mass of the big body and $m$ the mass of the small body. If you plug in $F=ma$ you will get that any orbiting body accelerates with
$$a=\frac{GM}{r^2}$$
If you want this orbit to be circular you can equate this acceleration to the centripetal acceleration. This leaves $v$ as the only independent variable. Which equation do you get when you do this?

For the bonus: in circular orbits you can use $v=\frac{2\pi}T r$ in your derived equation to relate $T$ with $r$. What do you get?

If you want to know where this formula for the period comes from you can use $x(t)=r\cos(\frac{2\pi}T t),\ y(t)=r\sin(\frac{2\pi}T t)$ to get $v_x(t)=-r\frac{2\pi}T\sin(\frac{2\pi}T t),\ v_y(t)=r\frac{2\pi}T\cos(\frac{2\pi}T t)$. Then use $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$.

Comment: "Which equation do you get when you do this?" That's why I asked the question. "to relate T with r." But you haven't defined what T is. Is T the time to complete a full orbit?

Comment: $T$ is indeed the time to complete a full orbit. My bad I should've defined that. On this site you're not supposed to give full answers to homework-like questions. You have to show at least some work. The final step is just rearranging terms so where do you get stuck? Do you get stuck when rearranging terms (the algebra) or do you not understand the equations?